# How to set the guest hardware time for QEMU from libvirt?

Tags: qemu, libvirt

I wish to set the virtualized hardware time to a fixed value upon
bootup. In Qemu, this is easy:

```
qemu-kvm \
    -rtc base=2011-11-11T11:11:00 \
    …
```

However I fail to see a way of adding this to a guest
configuration in libvirt (v2.2.0). [Some of the
parameters](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsTime)
of Qemu appear to be supported, but it would appear that *date*
is not among them. Is there another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out *libvirt* supports direct passing of command line
arguments to the Qemu backend. In order to “unlock” this
functionality, one needs to include the relevant namespace
in the guest definition:

```
-<domain type='kvm'>
+<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
```

Now one has access to the tag `commandline`. Inside it,
arguments are specified using a series of `arg` elements:

```
<qemu:commandline>
  <qemu:arg value='-rtc'/>
  <qemu:arg value='base=2011-11-11T11:11:00'/>
</qemu:commandline>
```

That end up being appended to Qemu’s `argv[]`.

Comment: It requires the guest in poweroff state and `systemctl restart libvirtd.service`